# Including images in R package documentation file

Tags: r, package, documentation, rd

In fact, I have the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189327/including-images-in-r-package-documentation-rd-files) than Teema Daniel Laajala, but the answer provided does not work for me.

The question was about displaying images in R package documention.
When I write exactly the same code than in the [?par documentation file](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/graphics/man/par.Rd), which is :

```
\item{\code{mai}}{A numerical vector of the form \code{c(bottom,
    left, top, right)} which gives the margin size specified in
  inches.\cr
  \if{html}{\figure{mai.png}{options: width="35\%" alt="Figure: mai.png"}}
  \if{latex}{\figure{mai.pdf}{options: width=7cm}}
}
```

the image does not display and all I can see is : [imagenotdisplayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6vF4.png).

Though, I did the exact same code as above, put my image in the folder figures in the folder man... 
So I was wondering If I was missing something, like a package I should install or something else...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Where did you put the image? It looks likes it needs to be int the `man/figures` folder (not the same place as the Rd file).

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake when I wrote the message, the image is in 'man/figures', not in 'man/image'.

Comment: Okay, for what it's worth, in fact it does work when I compile the package and use '? function' or 'help(function)', but the image does not display when I preview my file (function.Rd).